# JavaScript -- get current date using UTC offset

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get the current date based on UTC Offset? For example, the UTC Offset for Australia is UTC +10:00 where it is already May 24th.

I can get UTC date and hour but can't find any Date methods that factor in UTC Offset.

Comment: The easier way would probably be to use moment.js: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Australia and its territories have several time zones, ranging from +05:00 to +11:00.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you have the offset (in this case 10 hours) use this function:

```
function getDateWithUTCOffset(inputTzOffset){
    var now = new Date(); // get the current time

    var currentTzOffset = -now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60 // in hours, i.e. -4 in NY
    var deltaTzOffset = inputTzOffset - currentTzOffset; // timezone diff

    var nowTimestamp = now.getTime(); // get the number of milliseconds since unix epoch 
    var deltaTzOffsetMilli = deltaTzOffset * 1000 * 60 * 60; // convert hours to milliseconds (tzOffsetMilli*1000*60*60)
    var outputDate = new Date(nowTimestamp + deltaTzOffsetMilli) // your new Date object with the timezone offset applied.

    return outputDate;
}
```

In your case you would use:

```
var timeInAustralia = getDateWithUTCOffset(10);
```

This will return a `Date` object. You still need to format the date to your liking.

I agree with @Frax, Moment is a great library if you don't mind adding additional dependencies to your project.

Good luck

Comment: Not all offsets are whole hours. They are generally expressed as a string like "+05:30" or "+0530".

Comment: In that case you can use `5.5` as `inputTzOffset`

Answer (score 2):

Using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) it's very easy:

```
moment().tz("Australia/Sydney").format()
```

Answer (score 2):

Date objects have UTC methods, so if you have an offset like +10:00 you can simply apply it to the UTC time and then read the resulting UTC values. The offset can be applied as hours and minutes, or converted to a single value and applied, e.g.

```js
/*  Return a date in yyyy-mm-dd format for the provided offset
**  @param {string} offset - offset from GMT in format +/-hh:mm
**                         - default sign is +, default offset is 00:00
**  @returns {string} date at pffset in format yyyy-mm-dd
*/
function dateAtOffset(offset){
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  var d = new Date();
  var sign = /^\-/.test(offset)? -1 : +1;
  offset = offset.match(/\d\d/g) || [0,0];
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + sign*(offset[0]*60 + offset[1]*1))
  return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + z(d.getUTCDate());
}

var offset = '+10:00';
document.write('The date at GMT' + offset + ' is: ' + dateAtOffset(offset));
```

You can also adjust a date for the offset and read "local" values:

```js
function timeAtOffset(offset) {
  var d = new Date();
  var sign = /^\-/.test(offset)? -1 : 1;
  offset = offset.match(/\d\d/g) || [0,0];
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() + sign*(offset[0]*60 + offset[1]*1));
  return d;
}

var offset = '-04:00';
document.write('Time at GMT' + offset + ' is: ' + timeAtOffset(offset))
```

Note however that the default *toString* will report the local time zone offset, not the one to which it has been adjusted, so be careful when using such an object.